# How do I change playlists in Zombies Run 2?

Tags: ios, zombies-run

I've just installed the update for Zombies Run 2 and it is still using my old playlist from the first version. I want to switch to a different playlist but there no longer seems to be that option in the settings menu.

Would anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found you actually choose the play list when you select which mission you are about to go on. Right next to the 'start mission' button